# Can drop-down-lists control check boxes in a checkboxlist?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can drop-down-lists check or uncheck Checkboxes that are populated using ObjectDatasource. the values in the drop-down-lists represent Equipments and the Check Boxes represent Settings of these equipments. both Are stored in one table in the DB. Is It possible to accomplish that. What is the logic behind this approach if any. I have checked on line but I found nothing similar to this problem. it has been 3 day with noo luck. I Have gotten as far as storing the settings of the 
`EquipDDL.SelectedValue` in a list.
but I'm having a hard time binding the data of this list and the check Boxes List.

```
string UserDDL = AllEquipDDL.SelectedValue.ToString()
string query = "Select settingName from EquipSettings where EquipName=" + UserDDL;
cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd.CommandText = query;

SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (dr.Read())
{
    string myItem = dr["settingName"].ToString();

    settingSelectCheckBox.Items.Add(myItem);

    for (int i = 0; i <= settingSelectCheckBox.Items.Count; i++)
    // stucked in here...
```

ASP.NET:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList runat="server" ID="settingSelectCheckBox" DataSourceID="SettingsObjectDataSource"

<asp:DropDownList ID="AllEquipDDL" runat="server" DataSourceID="AllEquipSqlDataSource"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  string myItem = dr["settingName"].ToString();
  settingSelectCheckBox.Items.Add(myItem);
 IEnumerable<string> CheckedItems = settingSelectCheckBox.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
                                   .Where(i => i.Selected)
                                   .Select(i => i.Value);

      foreach(string i in CheckedItems)
      {
        //do somthing
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

the way I solved the problem by using Google chrome Developer tool to identify the Ids for all check boxes and all ddl items, Using if statements and else i was able to check and Uncheck desired checkBoxes.